# Can i output Memory address of array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

How to output memory address of array in C++? Is there a kind of method to do that?
I have 4 element in array and i wanna cout this elements and output the memory address of this elements.

Comment: What does "memory address of array" mean?

Comment: What operator do you usually use to take the address of things? Did you try it on your array and its elements? What happened?

Comment: I think good old `printf("The address is %p\n", myArray);` is a quick and useful way to get an address printed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. We may directly print the array's address, or print the first element's address, they are identical.

You can also use the `std::addressof`, which is introduced in c++11.

All these print statements get the same output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::cout << &arr << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr << std::endl;
  std::cout << &arr[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::addressof(arr) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::addressof(arr[0]) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/373ahTc64)

Comment: Now do the same thing for an array of `char`. <g> +1.